# How to set discount code for one country using only?

Tags: discount, rules

Can anyone help to teach me how to set specific discount code only for specific country only?

Thanks!

Comment: Specify please for which version of Magento, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**For Magento 2:** 
- Click on Marketing > Cart Price Rules and add new rule. 
- In Conditions tab, you can specify Shipping country: 
[image]

 
- You can also specify country using Customer attributes that you can find in this drop down.

If you are using Magento 1, it is the same but you should find this from Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules.